# swift mailer shows fatal error, connection refused

Tags: mandrill

i am trying to use swift mailer to send emails with mandrill API. I was working on a server and it worked great. Then when i changed to another server and it shows this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.mandrillapp.com [Connection refused #111]'
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically a result of your hosting provider blocking the port being used or blocking external SMTP connections. You'll likely want to get in touch with the host for the new server you're working with since many shared hosting providers limit or prohibit the use of certain ports or external services.

Comment: thank, this was helpful. I contacted my host and they opened the port..    :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had not mentioned port number 587. mandrillapp changed from default 25 to 587 now.